# how to wait until a program finishes to pipe the output

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to pass a program output as input to another program, but I don't know how to make it wait until the first one is finished.

```
npm run test | ./script.js
```

I'm trying to run that, but when I run it, tests are starting and the script is throwing an error immediately

Answer (score 2):

the pipe gets the standard output directly to standard input, you can use an subshell to execute first then get the standard output into the standard input.

```
./script.js <<< "$(npm run test)"
```

other way to do this is to store the output into an temp_file then use this file as input of the script

```
nmp run test >> temp_file ; ./script.js < temp_file
```

Comment: You should double-quote the here-string: `<<< "$(npm run test)"`. Some versions of bash had a really weird parsing bug if it wasn't double-quoted.

Comment: tks, i've edited the answer. I always forget to double-quote replacements and subshell before here-string.